# specify a time interval in which to execute a certain script

Tags: bash, cron, at

I have this bash script:

```
while [[ 1 ]] ; do sleep 3600 ; ./notify.sh --text "ricordati di bere" && play /mnt/musica/login.wav && zenity --info --text="<span size=\"xx-large\">Time is $(date +%Hh%M).</span>\n\nricordati di <b>bere</b>." --title="drink time" ; done
```

I'd like to execute this script (from 8:00 o'clock, less important) to 19:00 (most important); it's possible?
I have seen `at` command, but I didn't find how set "until" or "before".

This question is different from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478336/run-commands-at-a-specified-time)

Comment: Monday through Friday or 7 days a week? What if the script fired regularly but only notified between those hours?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would do the scheduling with cron.  The schedule would look like

```
0 8-19 * * * /path/to/script
```

or

```
0 8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19 * * * /path/to/script
```

and the script would look like

```sh
#!/bin/sh

./notify.sh --text "ricordati di bere" &&
play /mnt/musica/login.wav &&
zenity --info \
    --text="<span size=\"xx-large\">Time is $(date +%Hh%M)</span>\n\nricordati di <b>bere</b>." \
    --title="drink time"
```

See also "[How to send a mail for every 10 minutes through shell script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/517356)"

Comment: @Duns If you added the cron job as root, then it's added to root's crontab.  You would view root's crontab with `sudo crontab -l`. However, I just realised that you are trying to use GUI applications, so using cron for this may not be the easiest solution. Cron jobs have no connection to the display and can't generally open dialog boxes or windows.

Comment: thanks. It seems work, *somehow* (maybe not perfectly; btw I dont' use a GUI): at 8:00 I received on my smartphone the notify, when I was not at home;  but coming back to home I didn't see the pop-up. So I tried double-click on the script and it works perfectly. I will see at 9:00.  Another thing: if I would do from 8:30 to 11:30 and from 15:30 to 18:30, it should possible with cron?

Comment: @Duns See `man 5 crontab`.  `30 8-11,15-18 * * * /path/to/script`

Comment: Thank you very much. It works, but only the sound and the smartphone notify, not the PC pop-up. I started a new session. I will see.

Comment: @Duns This is what I mentioned in my first comment. Running graphical applications from cron is difficult as the environment that the cron jobs run in does not have direct access to the screen. The script may need to explicitly do something like `export DISPLAY=:0.0` followed by `export XAUTHORITY=/home/me/.Xauthority` (where `/home/me` is the home directory of the user running the desktop environment).  This is untested as I don't run Linux and don't use `zenity`.

Comment: It works: I added  "--display=:0.0" to zenity command in bash script (as said [here](http://promberger.info/linux/2009/01/02/running-x-apps-like-zenity-from-crontab-solving-cannot-open-display-problem/)). Not what you said, even you gave me a great help. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you use Linux, [timeout](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/timeout.1.html) is the simplest way to do this. 08:00 to 19:00 is 11 hours, so we tell timeout to run the script for 11 hours.

```
timeout 11h /home/username/script
```

Start the job with cron at 08:00 (or manually whenever you wish) and have it killed automatically at 19:00 sharp with another cron entry

```
kill -9 /home/username/script
```

Comment: Thanks, but I start the Pc non always at the same time, so your solution is not what I search for.

Comment: See rephrasing above which shows greater flexibility.